# how to merge folders in python?

Tags: python

How to remove part of a tree but keep the files and directories in python?

I have paths like this:

```
r"C:\User\Desktop\g1sr56g41f2d3s1gf\Document\A\file1.txt"
r"C:\User\Desktop\g1sr56g41f2d3s1gf\Document\B\C\file2.txt"
r"C:\User\Desktop\g1sr56g41f2d3s1gf\file3.txt"
r"C:\User\Desktop\F2F31DS5FDSF1S2F3DS2F1D23\file4.txt"
r"C:\User\Desktop\g1sr56g41f2d3s1gf\Document\B\C\file5.txt"
r"C:\User\Desktop\g1sr56g41f2d3s1gf\Document\D\E\file6.txt"
```

I want to move them to:

```
r"C:\User\Desktop\Document\A\file1.txt"
r"C:\User\Desktop\Document\B\C\file2.txt"
r"C:\User\Desktop\file3.txt"
r"C:\User\Desktop\file4.txt"
r"C:\User\Desktop\Document\B\C\file5.txt"
r"C:\User\Desktop\Document\D\E\file6.txt"
```

Comment: Everything starts after desktop?

Comment: Do you want everything to be moved into Desktop? Really?

Comment: @Bhargav yes (and to Zain, no, this is an illustrative example)

Comment: That path is tricky/buggy...idk why been trying from past 1 hour not able to proccess it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOme simply dirty way to do it

```
import os
paths = r"C:\User\Desktop\g1sr56g41f2d3s1gf\Document\D\E\file6.txt"
path = paths.replace(os.sep, '/')
l=(list(path.split("/")))

trim = l[3]
print(trim)
final_path = path.replace("/"+trim,'')
final_path = final_path.replace('/', os.sep)
print(final_path)
```

output

```
C:\User\Desktop\Document\D\E\file6.txt
```

### Solution 2

```
import os
import re
paths = r"C:\User\Desktop\g1sr56g41f2d3s1gf\Document\D\E\file6.txt"
path = paths.replace(os.sep, '/')

l=(list(path.split("/")))


del l[3]

final_path = os.sep.join(l)
print(final_path)
```

output

```
C:\User\Desktop\Document\D\E\file6.txt
```

Comment: @cy614 worked?.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os, shutil

DST = 'Desktop'

toDel = []
for folder_name in os.listdir(DST):
    folder = os.path.join(DST, folder_name)
    if not os.path.isdir(folder):
        continue
    for path, _, files in os.walk(folder):
        relpath = os.path.join(DST, os.path.relpath(path, folder))
        for file in files:
            search = os.path.join(path, file)
            destination = os.path.join(relpath, file)
            if not os.path.exists(relpath):
                os.mkdir(relpath)
            os.replace(search, destination)
        if len(toDel) == 0 or not path.startswith(toDel[-1] + os.sep):
            toDel.append(path)
for folder in toDel:
    shutil.rmtree(folder)
```